# jqGrid computed columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Anyone have an idea of how to create computed columns. For e.g. I have a grid like:

```
$("#myProductGrid").jqGrid({
  url:DUMMY_URL,
  dataType:"local",
  width:285,
  colNames:['Item', 'Unit Price', 'Qty', 'Discount', 'Sale Price'],
  colModel:[ 
    {name:'description', index:'description', summaryType:'count'}, 
    {name:'unit_price', index:'unit_price', align:"right", sorttype:"float"}, 
    {name:'quantity', index:'quantity', formatter:'number', summaryType:'sum'}, 
    {name:'item_id', index:'item_id', hidden:true}, 
    {name:'discount_percent', index:'discount_percent', align:"right", sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'sale_price', index:'sale_price', align:"right", sorttype:"float", summaryType:'sum'},
   ],
 ... 
 });
```

I would like the "sale price" column to display `quantity*(unit_price - (unit_price*discount))`

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

try to use afterInserted Row event

Comment: the way i got this done was to compute the columns in the model itself.Lame but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to accomplish something similar, to sum the total of a price column:

```
//Count total for a price column
var total = 0;
$('#table tr').each(function(){

    //cells that contains the price
    var tdprice = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html();

    //Sum it up!
    if (isNaN(tdprice)){ total += parseInt(tdprice); }
});

alert(total + "$");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a JQuery plugin, **[Sumtr](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-sumtr)**, which does summation on an arbitrary table.

Check out the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hZqGg/).